# How to fix a content cant be displayed error when open file using intent?

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I want to programmatically show a file, using intent, to another app, like pdf-viewer. But no app can resolves the content of file and show error message or closes immediately. I think my app will not send the content of a file correct, so that other apps cant show the file.

I've searched for a solution, but found only comments and posts, where the problem is to open the file. But thats not my problem.

Here my code(not really mine, i got it from another website) to open the file:

```java
        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(filetype);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",file);
            intent.setDataAndType(fileURI, mimeType);

        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
         }
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Application found to open this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

The String-var 'filetype' is the file extension/type e.g. "pdf" or "txt" and getting correct mimetype is no problem.
The File-object 'file' is my file, i created on this way:

```java
File openFile = new File("MY_PATH");
```

There is also no problem.

So where is the error or have anyone better code or could post a link to a good blog/stack-overflow-post or else, related to my topic?
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: have you added your content provider to Manifest?

Comment: Yes, i did. And [BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider"] is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to share image, hope it helps:

```
    private const val IMAGE_FORMAT = "image/jpg"

  override fun shareFile(file: File) {
     if (context != null) {
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, FileManager.PROVIDER, file)

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intent.type = IMAGE_FORMAT
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share_via)))
    }
}
```

`FileManager.PROVIDER` is provider String in your case `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will try this code and give you feedback, whether it works :D

Comment: I've tried, without success. Is it possible that i create the file object not correct??